# Stata esttab Output

Tags: stata, lyx

I have a simple but strange issue cropping up when I use `esttab` to export results from Stata into LaTeX.

Once the output is stored in the tex file I import the file into Lyx. However all coefficients are preceded by `[em1]` which complies as text in the pdf. Even if I don't import the tex file into Lyx and open it in Texworks, the `[em1]` prefix still appears. The only way I can find to remove the `[em1]` is manually which is tedious and lacks elegance.

Any ideas why this appears?

Here's the generating code:

```
svyset w1_wgt
estpost  svy: tab reason1, se per
est store w1, title(Model 1)

svyset w2_wgt
estpost  svy: tab reason2, se per
est store w2

svyset w3_wgt
estpost  svy: tab reason3, se per
est store w3

esttab w1 w2 w3 ///
using "Output/Descriptive Statistics/Absence of Adults.tex" ///
, replace nostar se unstack label  tex
```

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question, but you can use `filefilter` to  get rid of the undesired text:

```
clear all
set more off

eststo clear
webuse nhanes2f

svyset psuid

svy: tab sex, se per
est store w1

svy: tab race, se per
est store w2

svy: tab region, se per
est store w3

esttab w1 w2 w3 using "D:/Desktop/statatemps/Absence.tex", ///
    replace nostar se unstack label tex

filefilter ///
    "D:/Desktop/statatemps/Absence.tex" ///
        "D:/Desktop/statatemps/Absence2.tex", from("[1em]") to("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try working with outreg instead. Following @RobertoFerrer's example (thanks for giving some working code), you can use `outreg` instead of `esttab`:

```
outreg using "C:\...\Absence2.tex", replace nostar se tex
```

Then just play with the formatting options in outreg. If it has what you need, this might be an easier way to achieve what you want. I have always found `esttab` to be better for these tabulations when I need them in MS Excel and `outreg` better for TeX. Just IMO, though.

Answer (score 0):

this does not appear to be a Stata problem (so you can remove that tag), but a LyX problem. The `[1em]` insert (you wrote `[em1]` and I'm assuming that's a typo) tells LaTeX how much space to put in between the rows (see my screenshot when I compile the table in Overleaf).

```
\begin{tabular}{l*{3}{c}}
\hline\hline
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean}\\
\hline
p11                 &       0.475&       0.876&       0.202\\
                    &   (0.00254)&   (0.00194)&   (0.00150)\\
[1em]
p21                 &       0.525&       0.105&       0.268\\
                    &   (0.00254)&   (0.00452)&   (0.00600)\\
[1em]
p31                 &            &      0.0193&       0.276\\
                    &            &   (0.00647)&   (0.00414)\\
[1em]
p41                 &            &            &       0.254\\
                    &            &            &   (0.00864)\\
\hline
Observations        &       10337&       10337&       10337\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\end{tabular}
```

This table compiles in Overleaf even in a completely bare-bones document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{test.tex} % This is what I called your table. FWIW I would never put spaces in a file name.
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot from Overleaf]

So what you need to figure out next is **why LyX is compiling so oddly**. If you want more help, please let us know your preamble of loaded packages in LyX and also a screenshot of the table the way it compiles.